# bridging ethernet to wifi is not working

Tags: debian, dhcp, bridge

I have an external board that I am programming. This board has an ethernet connection. What I want to do is connect the board to the internet by plugging the board into my computer and using the wireless interface from my computer with which my computer is connected to the internet. My interfaces are called wlo1 for the wireless iface and enp0s25 for the wired iface. I used following commands to set up the bridge

```
brctl addbr br0
iw dev wlo1 set 4addr on
brctl addif br0 enp0s25 wlo1
dhclient -d br0
```

However, this is not working. The last command does not get an ip address from the dhcp server. To be more specific, here is a drawing from the setup:

```
################                    ##################        ethernet        ##################
# The Internet # ------ WiFi ------ # Linux computer # ------  cable   ------ # external board #
################                    ##################                        ##################
```

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Bridging WLAN and LAN doesn't always work (on some embedded systems it does). Consider doing forwarding + masquerading instead.

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable forwarding on your computer to make it work.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

or

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: Forwarding is not bridging ... yes, he can do forwarding, but it will do something different.